# outlook rules not working automatically

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am using outlook 2007 and am using wsus to install all the updates to the client.I have created the rules and alerts in outlook 2007 but some of the mails are not getting delivered to the concerned folder.Please give suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this Microsoft Support article can help:
[After you configure one or more client-only message rules in Outlook, other message rules do not take effect](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892240)

The thread [Outlook 2007 - rules do not run automatically](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5206-6230-0.html;jsessionid=B0223590334DD27392F2AA201D11B192?forumID=101&threadID=256348&start=0&tag=content;leftCol) contains some more advice :

1. Turning off Use Cached Exchange Mode
2. Export, delete and re-import the rules, restarting Outlook at every step

The thread [Microsoft Outlook 2007 Rules not working help](http://www.pc-pals.com/smf/windows-general-software-help/microsoft-outlook-2007-rules-not-working-help/15/) claims that all email addresses should be defined as contacts before the rule is created.

Apparently, making Outlook rules work is somewhat of a black art.

Comment: I have one rule created and got some server error. I cannot open / edit / delete the rule after. And I don't see the rule in webmail either. I tried the 2nd approach: "Export, delete and re-import the rules, restarting Outlook at every step". After I re-import the rules, all my rules are not working anymore. Now I have to re-create my 50 rules from scrath again.

Comment: The links provided were not any help in my case. I followed the steps in the MS article even with empty rules and just adding server side catigory rules they would not work.  Im using 2010 though I see the same in all versions of office.

Answer (score -1):

As a long suffering Outlook user who has finally persuaded his company to go Google, just forget about using Outlook rules unless they are server based, they just don't work without constant supervision.